# Why can't we divide set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We can multiply sets , add and subtract sets which are called union and intersection. But why can't we divide sets?

Comment: You can *partition* a set into disjoint subsets, whose union exactly matches the original set.  I suppose that if you add the constraint that each subset has the same number of elements, that might be construed as *dividing* the set.

Comment: Intersection doesn't really behave like subtraction, and the set operation that behave more like addition is *disjoint* union, not regular union.

Comment: Re my previous comment, one example that involves a set with an infinite number of elements is: *dividing* the integers into $~\{\cdots, -3, 0, 3, \cdots\}, ~\{\cdots, -2, 1, 4, \cdots\}, ~\{\cdots, -1, 2, 5, \cdots\},~$ where the partitioning is based on the remainder, when the number is divided by $(3)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you need more structure.  They are called quotient groups and quotient rings.

By multiply sets I assume you mean the Cartesian product.  It is also possible to define lots of other kinds of product.  For some of those, the inverse operation will make sense and you have division.

Comment: Actually, I would argue that a set can be *divided* without the set being associated with any operation on the elements of the set.  See my comment following the question.

Answer (score 0):

Division is the opposite of multiplication. If you consider set multiplication to be intersection, then we want an operation that, in some sense, 'undoes' intersection. Let this operation be denoted $\oslash$. Then,

$A\cap B=C\implies A=C\oslash B$

Now, perhaps with a Venn diagram, think about what you could do with $C$ and $B$ to recover $A$. Is there such an operation? If there is, it's not very useful, because the answer isn't unique $-$ you could modify $A$ into $A'$ so that it includes more elements that aren't in $B$. Then $A\cap B=A'\cap B$. So what should $C\oslash B$ yield, $A$ or $A'$? We don't know. So $\oslash$ isn't useful to think about.